# How many whole number solutions does this system of inequalities have? $2\leqslant x_1+x_2+x_3\leqslant5$

Tags: combinatorics, systems-of-equations

This is the beginning of the problem. I don't understand why there is ≤1...

$\{2 ≤ x_1 + x_2 + x_3 ≤ 5\} = \{x_1 + x_2 + x_3 ≤ 5\}\setminus\{x_1 + x_2 + x_3 ≤ 1\}$

$\binom{3+5}{5}
= 56 $

$\binom{3+1}{
1}
= 4$

$56−4 = 52$
So the number is $52$.

But why is there an inequality ≤1??

Answer (score 2):

Very simply, we counted the number of solutions to $x_1+x_2+x_3\leq 5$ where we ignored a lower bound.  We then corrected our count by removing those outcomes from what we were counting that violated the lower bound.

Violating the lower bound in $2\leq x_1+x_2+x_3\leq 5$ means that $x_1+x_2+x_3<2$

Since we are talking about whole numbers being strictly less than $2$ means the same thing as being less than or equal to $1$ since there are no possibilities between the two.